# vb .net iterate dynamic json

Tags: json, vb.net, loops

I have dynamic jSON that could contain keys and subkeys.
Since each jSON could have more or less keys/subkeys (some of they may or not appear), I'd like to iterate the Object and get all information (key and value). My problem is this iteration since I don't see how can I achieve this.

```
Dim JSON_Obj1 As Object = New JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(JSON_Response)
```

When trying to access data:

```
        For Each j In JSON_Obj1
            Console.WriteLine(j.ToString)
        Next
```

This code outputs the data like:
If it's a key:

```
[id, 130ee895-1e5e-4f82-bb66-e1275bac75dd]
```

if it's a subkey:

```
[image_uris, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]]
```

After checking my j var, I don't have many options that could get that information.
How can I achieve this automatically, without need to make checks if keys exists and retrieve their value and key name?

Edit: Added 2 jSON example

```
{
  "object": "card",
  "id": "3606519e-5677-4c21-a34e-be195b6669fa",
  "oracle_id": "35ae7b25-6d0f-49f8-a40d-dd2cf88e6f44",
  "multiverse_ids": [
    503627,
    503626
  ],
  "mtgo_id": 87365,
  "arena_id": 75057,
  "tcgplayer_id": 230921,
  "cardmarket_id": 532112,
  "name": "Reidane, God of the Worthy // Valkmira, Protector's Shield",
  "lang": "en",
  "released_at": "2021-02-05",
  "uri": "https://api.scryfall.com/cards/3606519e-5677-4c21-a34e-be195b6669fa",
  "scryfall_uri": "https://scryfall.com/card/khm/21/reidane-god-of-the-worthy-valkmira-protectors-shield?utm_source=api",
  "layout": "modal_dfc",
  "highres_image": false,
  "cmc": 3.0,
  "type_line": "Legendary Creature — God // Legendary Artifact",
  "color_identity": [
    "W"
  ],
  "keywords": [
    "Flying",
    "Vigilance"
  ],
  "card_faces": [
    {
      "object": "card_face",
      "name": "Reidane, God of the Worthy",
      "mana_cost": "{2}{W}",
      "type_line": "Legendary Creature — God",
      "oracle_text": "Flying, vigilance\nSnow lands your opponents control enter the battlefield tapped.\nNoncreature spells your opponents cast with converted mana cost 4 or greater cost {2} more to cast.",
      "colors": [
        "W"
      ],
      "power": "2",
      "toughness": "3",
      "artist": "Jason Rainville",
      "artist_id": "6ed7e669-579b-443d-b223-e5cbcb2a7483",
      "illustration_id": "50842425-89ab-475d-afce-b43b28f9aa43",
      "image_uris": {
        "small": "https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/small/front/3/6/3606519e-5677-4c21-a34e-be195b6669fa.jpg?1611000242",
        "normal": "https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/normal/front/3/6/3606519e-5677-4c21-a34e-be195b6669fa.jpg?1611000242",
        "large": "https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/large/front/3/6/3606519e-5677-4c21-a34e-be195b6669fa.jpg?1611000242",
        "png": "https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/png/front/3/6/3606519e-5677-4c21-a34e-be195b6669fa.png?1611000242",
        "art_crop": "https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/art_crop/front/3/6/3606519e-5677-4c21-a34e-be195b6669fa.jpg?1611000242",
        "border_crop": "https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/border_crop/front/3/6/3606519e-5677-4c21-a34e-be195b6669fa.jpg?1611000242"
      }
    },
    {
      "object": "card_face",
      "name": "Valkmira, Protector's Shield",
      "mana_cost": "{3}{W}",
      "type_line": "Legendary Artifact",
      "oracle_text": "If a source an opponent controls would deal damage to you or a permanent you control, prevent 1 of that damage.\nWhenever you or a permanent you control becomes the target of a spell or ability an opponent controls, counter that spell or ability unless its controller pays {1}.",
      "colors": [
        "W"
      ],
      "artist": "Jason Rainville",
      "artist_id": "6ed7e669-579b-443d-b223-e5cbcb2a7483",
      "illustration_id": "d8a037ea-c67b-4290-81ef-cdb8073c46cb",
      "image_uris": {
        "small": "https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/small/back/3/6/3606519e-5677-4c21-a34e-be195b6669fa.jpg?1611000242",
        "normal": "https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/normal/back/3/6/3606519e-5677-4c21-a34e-be195b6669fa.jpg?1611000242",
        "large": "https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/large/back/3/6/3606519e-5677-4c21-a34e-be195b6669fa.jpg?1611000242",
        "png": "https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/png/back/3/6/3606519e-5677-4c21-a34e-be195b6669fa.png?1611000242",
        "art_crop": "https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/art_crop/back/3/6/3606519e-5677-4c21-a34e-be195b6669fa.jpg?1611000242",
        "border_crop": "https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/border_crop/back/3/6/3606519e-5677-4c21-a34e-be195b6669fa.jpg?1611000242"
      }
    }
  ],
  "legalities": {
    "standard": "legal",
    "future": "legal",
    "historic": "legal",
    "gladiator": "legal",
    "pioneer": "legal",
    "modern": "legal",
    "legacy": "legal",
    "pauper": "not_legal",
    "vintage": "legal",
    "penny": "not_legal",
    "commander": "legal",
    "brawl": "legal",
    "duel": "legal",
    "oldschool": "not_legal",
    "premodern": "not_legal"
  },
  "games": [
    "arena",
    "paper",
    "mtgo"
  ],
  "reserved": false,
  "foil": true,
  "nonfoil": true,
  "oversized": false,
  "promo": false,
  "reprint": false,
  "variation": false,
  "set": "khm",
  "set_name": "Kaldheim",
  "set_type": "expansion",
  "set_uri": "https://api.scryfall.com/sets/43057fad-b1c1-437f-bc48-0045bce6d8c9",
  "set_search_uri": "https://api.scryfall.com/cards/search?order=set&q=e%3Akhm&unique=prints",
  "scryfall_set_uri": "https://scryfall.com/sets/khm?utm_source=api",
  "rulings_uri": "https://api.scryfall.com/cards/3606519e-5677-4c21-a34e-be195b6669fa/rulings",
  "prints_search_uri": "https://api.scryfall.com/cards/search?order=released&q=oracleid%3A35ae7b25-6d0f-49f8-a40d-dd2cf88e6f44&unique=prints",
  "collector_number": "21",
  "digital": false,
  "rarity": "rare",
  "card_back_id": "0aeebaf5-8c7d-4636-9e82-8c27447861f7",
  "artist": "Jason Rainville",
  "artist_ids": [
    "6ed7e669-579b-443d-b223-e5cbcb2a7483"
  ],
  "border_color": "black",
  "frame": "2015",
  "frame_effects": [
    "legendary"
  ],
  "full_art": false,
  "textless": false,
  "booster": true,
  "story_spotlight": false,
  "edhrec_rank": 15706,
  "preview": {
    "source": "Marty Friedman",
    "source_uri": "https://twitter.com/marty_friedman/status/1349527247560994816",
    "previewed_at": "2021-01-13"
  },
  "prices": {
    "usd": "0.87",
    "usd_foil": "5.68",
    "eur": "1.37",
    "eur_foil": "2.00",
    "tix": null
  },
  "related_uris": {
    "gatherer": "https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=503627",
    "tcgplayer_decks": "https://decks.tcgplayer.com/magic/deck/search?contains=Reidane%2C+God+of+the+Worthy&page=1&utm_campaign=affiliate&utm_medium=api&utm_source=scryfall",
    "edhrec": "https://edhrec.com/route/?cc=Reidane%2C+God+of+the+Worthy",
    "mtgtop8": "https://mtgtop8.com/search?MD_check=1&SB_check=1&cards=Reidane%2C+God+of+the+Worthy"
  },
  "purchase_uris": {
    "tcgplayer": "https://shop.tcgplayer.com/product/productsearch?id=230921&utm_campaign=affiliate&utm_medium=api&utm_source=scryfall",
    "cardmarket": "https://www.cardmarket.com/en/Magic/Products/Singles/Kaldheim/Reidane-God-of-the-Worthy-Valkmira-Protectors-Shield?referrer=scryfall&utm_campaign=card_prices&utm_medium=text&utm_source=scryfall",
    "cardhoarder": "https://www.cardhoarder.com/cards/87365?affiliate_id=scryfall&ref=card-profile&utm_campaign=affiliate&utm_medium=card&utm_source=scryfall"
  }
}
```

Example 2:

```
{
  "object": "card",
  "id": "03595195-3be2-4d18-b5c0-43b2dcc1c0f5",
  "oracle_id": "eeb07c8a-21d1-43fa-a5f3-ee3fe328a671",
  "multiverse_ids": [
    503625
  ],
  "mtgo_id": 87361,
  "arena_id": 75056,
  "tcgplayer_id": 230200,
  "cardmarket_id": 530517,
  "name": "Rally the Ranks",
  "lang": "en",
  "released_at": "2021-02-05",
  "uri": "https://api.scryfall.com/cards/03595195-3be2-4d18-b5c0-43b2dcc1c0f5",
  "scryfall_uri": "https://scryfall.com/card/khm/20/rally-the-ranks?utm_source=api",
  "layout": "normal",
  "highres_image": false,
  "image_uris": {
    "small": "https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/small/front/0/3/03595195-3be2-4d18-b5c0-43b2dcc1c0f5.jpg?1610585956",
    "normal": "https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/normal/front/0/3/03595195-3be2-4d18-b5c0-43b2dcc1c0f5.jpg?1610585956",
    "large": "https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/large/front/0/3/03595195-3be2-4d18-b5c0-43b2dcc1c0f5.jpg?1610585956",
    "png": "https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/png/front/0/3/03595195-3be2-4d18-b5c0-43b2dcc1c0f5.png?1610585956",
    "art_crop": "https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/art_crop/front/0/3/03595195-3be2-4d18-b5c0-43b2dcc1c0f5.jpg?1610585956",
    "border_crop": "https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/border_crop/front/0/3/03595195-3be2-4d18-b5c0-43b2dcc1c0f5.jpg?1610585956"
  },
  "mana_cost": "{1}{W}",
  "cmc": 2.0,
  "type_line": "Enchantment",
  "oracle_text": "As Rally the Ranks enters the battlefield, choose a creature type.\nCreatures you control of the chosen type get +1/+1.",
  "colors": [
    "W"
  ],
  "color_identity": [
    "W"
  ],
  "keywords": [

  ],
  "legalities": {
    "standard": "legal",
    "future": "legal",
    "historic": "legal",
    "gladiator": "legal",
    "pioneer": "legal",
    "modern": "legal",
    "legacy": "legal",
    "pauper": "not_legal",
    "vintage": "legal",
    "penny": "not_legal",
    "commander": "legal",
    "brawl": "legal",
    "duel": "legal",
    "oldschool": "not_legal",
    "premodern": "not_legal"
  },
  "games": [
    "arena",
    "paper",
    "mtgo"
  ],
  "reserved": false,
  "foil": true,
  "nonfoil": true,
  "oversized": false,
  "promo": false,
  "reprint": false,
  "variation": false,
  "set": "khm",
  "set_name": "Kaldheim",
  "set_type": "expansion",
  "set_uri": "https://api.scryfall.com/sets/43057fad-b1c1-437f-bc48-0045bce6d8c9",
  "set_search_uri": "https://api.scryfall.com/cards/search?order=set&q=e%3Akhm&unique=prints",
  "scryfall_set_uri": "https://scryfall.com/sets/khm?utm_source=api",
  "rulings_uri": "https://api.scryfall.com/cards/03595195-3be2-4d18-b5c0-43b2dcc1c0f5/rulings",
  "prints_search_uri": "https://api.scryfall.com/cards/search?order=released&q=oracleid%3Aeeb07c8a-21d1-43fa-a5f3-ee3fe328a671&unique=prints",
  "collector_number": "20",
  "digital": false,
  "rarity": "rare",
  "flavor_text": "Halvar united the spirits of all the clans into a single, devastating force.",
  "card_back_id": "0aeebaf5-8c7d-4636-9e82-8c27447861f7",
  "artist": "Lie Setiawan",
  "artist_ids": [
    "6f771d3f-310e-4aa4-841f-5ba4ba9f025a"
  ],
  "illustration_id": "6bdfe9e1-8e5b-486d-a338-160472efdf3f",
  "border_color": "black",
  "frame": "2015",
  "full_art": false,
  "textless": false,
  "booster": true,
  "story_spotlight": false,
  "edhrec_rank": 17953,
  "preview": {
    "source": "iYingdi",
    "source_uri": "https://www.iyingdi.com/web/bbspost/detail/2338086",
    "previewed_at": "2021-01-09"
  },
  "prices": {
    "usd": "0.34",
    "usd_foil": "1.34",
    "eur": "0.39",
    "eur_foil": "0.50",
    "tix": "0.02"
  },
  "related_uris": {
    "gatherer": "https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=503625",
    "tcgplayer_decks": "https://decks.tcgplayer.com/magic/deck/search?contains=Rally+the+Ranks&page=1&utm_campaign=affiliate&utm_medium=api&utm_source=scryfall",
    "edhrec": "https://edhrec.com/route/?cc=Rally+the+Ranks",
    "mtgtop8": "https://mtgtop8.com/search?MD_check=1&SB_check=1&cards=Rally+the+Ranks"
  },
  "purchase_uris": {
    "tcgplayer": "https://shop.tcgplayer.com/product/productsearch?id=230200&utm_campaign=affiliate&utm_medium=api&utm_source=scryfall",
    "cardmarket": "https://www.cardmarket.com/en/Magic/Products/Search?referrer=scryfall&searchString=Rally+the+Ranks&utm_campaign=card_prices&utm_medium=text&utm_source=scryfall",
    "cardhoarder": "https://www.cardhoarder.com/cards/87361?affiliate_id=scryfall&ref=card-profile&utm_campaign=affiliate&utm_medium=card&utm_source=scryfall"
  }
}
```

Edit 2:
Using newtonsoft json I've been able to get the not nested information:

```
    For Each item As JProperty In jss.Item("data")
        Dim itemObjects As JToken = item.Value
        Console.WriteLine(item.Name & " - " & itemObjects.ToString)
    Next
```

My question now is how to make it keep nesting and retrieve all other information.

Comment: Use `Json.Net` or `System.Text.Json` (it's also available for .Net Framework, as a NuGet Package). -- Can't you build a class model that describes that JSON, so it's much easier to handle? The *model* can contain all possible properties of a JSON, only those that are present when the JSON is deserialized are considered, but you can also use default values for missing properties.

Comment: It could be a possibility, but I'm not very good at vb .net to make a class like that. I Will take a look at those suggestions.

Comment: You can find on-line tools that provide JSON-to-.Net Classes services, as [QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io/). This is a very good tool, it doesn't create classes for VB.Net, just C# (in relation to .Net), but you can easily convert to this other language, it's almost the same thing.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. But I don't know if could be a solution for me since it's a small app to consume an API and I would need to learn how to do it and how to use it. Thanks. Despite of using it or not, I'll get it a check.

Comment: http://jsonutils.com is one of the converter sites that can create VB directly

Comment: When you have built the class model, what you do is `dim result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of MyRootObject)(jsonString)`, that's all. After that, you have .Net classes you can access as usual. -- Give it a try, post back if you have problems. Btw, you can find a ton of questions related to deserialization with `Json.Net` or `System.Text.Json`. But you can also test `JavaScriptSerializer`, it may get it right.

Comment: Yeah just found that site. But I can't understand how can I create a class if I don't know which are the keys at 100%? There could appear a json that contain a key that I don't have in my class yet. For that reason I would prefer to iterate all json file. Or I'm missing something here? Even the keys are dynamic, not only the values.

Comment: *Dynamic* keys can often be treated as a Dictionary. It depends on the structure of that JSON. -- If you want some more suggestions, you should post the JSON structure. Make some queries, get the JSON(s), check what's different, add what's missing, post the most complete JSON you can come up with.

Comment: I've added two examples of possible json. Please take note somethings keys change place. (from key to subkey for example)

Comment: The JSONs are consistent. The second one is missing the `card_faces` property, which is an Array or List of objects. You can compose the most complete JSON you can get by adding all parts to another JSON (using, e.g., Notepad or Visual Studio's text template for JSON), then build the class model with that. Add missing parts if you come across any. -- BTW, APIs usually describe the full JSON structure they provide (the full JSON response, when requested).

Comment: It seems weird .NET doesn't have a way to iterate into all jSON. That would led me to unecessary work of try and error (since I'm new to http requests, classes, dictionaries, etc). Thanks. will try to check but I guess duplicated "entries" will give me an headeach since I will have multiple "png" keys somewhere in that one json file. Thanks.

Comment: *It seems weird .NET doesn't have a way to iterate into all jSON* - of course it has a way to iterate into the json, you just haven't written it yet

Comment: Added a piece of code that iterate 1st level. Now my problem is getting him to iterate nested levels until there is no more levels. Any help?

Comment: I'm looking for something like "If item.HasValues = True Then" . But to check if it's a new nested level or not. I can't find anything that would check if it's or not a nested level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so you're looking to flatten your JSON.

```
Private Shared Sub FlattenInto(ByVal o As Object, ByVal into As StringBuilder)
    If TypeOf o Is JObject
        For Each t As KeyValuePair(Of String, JToken) In CType(o, JObject)
            FlattenInto(t.Value, into)
        Next
    Else If TypeOf o Is JArray
        For Each e In CType(o, JArray)
            FlattenInto(e, into)
        Next
    Else If TypeOf o is JValue
        Dim jValue = CType(o, JValue)
        into.AppendLine($"{jValue.Path}:{jValue.Value}")
    Else
        Throw New Exception($"Unsupported type: {o.[GetType]()}")
    End If
End Sub


Dim d = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(YOUR_JSON)

Dim sb = new StringBuilder()
FlattenInto(d, sb)
```

`sb` now contains like:

```
object:card
id:3606519e-5677-4c21-a34e-be195b6669fa
oracle_id:35ae7b25-6d0f-49f8-a40d-dd2cf88e6f44
multiverse_ids[0]:503627
multiverse_ids[1]:503626
mtgo_id:87365
arena_id:75057
tcgplayer_id:230921
cardmarket_id:532112
name:Reidane, God of the Worthy // Valkmira, Protector's Shield
lang:en
released_at:2021-02-05
uri:https://api.scryfall.com/cards/3606519e-5677-4c21-a34e-be195b6669fa
scryfall_uri:https://scryfall.com/card/khm/21/reidane-god-of-the-worthy-valkmira-protectors-shield?utm_source=api
layout:modal_dfc
highres_image:False
cmc:3
type_line:Legendary Creature — God // Legendary Artifact
color_identity[0]:W
keywords[0]:Flying
keywords[1]:Vigilance
card_faces[0].object:card_face
card_faces[0].name:Reidane, God of the Worthy
card_faces[0].mana_cost:{2}{W}
card_faces[0].type_line:Legendary Creature — God
card_faces[0].oracle_text:Flying, vigilance
Snow lands your opponents control enter the battlefield tapped.
Noncreature spells your opponents cast with converted mana cost 4 or greater cost {2} more to cast.
card_faces[0].colors[0]:W
card_faces[0].power:2
card_faces[0].toughness:3
card_faces[0].artist:Jason Rainville
card_faces[0].artist_id:6ed7e669-579b-443d-b223-e5cbcb2a7483
card_faces[0].illustration_id:50842425-89ab-475d-afce-b43b28f9aa43
card_faces[0].image_uris.small:https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/small/front/3/6/3606519e-5677-4c21-a34e-be195b6669fa.jpg?1611000242
card_faces[0].image_uris.normal:https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/normal/front/3/6/3606519e-5677-4c21-a34e-be195b6669fa.jpg?1611000242
card_faces[0].image_uris.large:https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/large/front/3/6/3606519e-5677-4c21-a34e-be195b6669fa.jpg?1611000242
card_faces[0].image_uris.png:https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/png/front/3/6/3606519e-5677-4c21-a34e-be195b6669fa.png?1611000242
card_faces[0].image_uris.art_crop:https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/art_crop/front/3/6/3606519e-5677-4c21-a34e-be195b6669fa.jpg?1611000242
card_faces[0].image_uris.border_crop:https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/border_crop/front/3/6/3606519e-5677-4c21-a34e-be195b6669fa.jpg?1611000242
card_faces[1].object:card_face
card_faces[1].name:Valkmira, Protector's Shield
card_faces[1].mana_cost:{3}{W}
card_faces[1].type_line:Legendary Artifact
card_faces[1].oracle_text:If a source an opponent controls would deal damage to you or a permanent you control, prevent 1 of that damage.
Whenever you or a permanent you control becomes the target of a spell or ability an opponent controls, counter that spell or ability unless its controller pays {1}.
card_faces[1].colors[0]:W
card_faces[1].artist:Jason Rainville
card_faces[1].artist_id:6ed7e669-579b-443d-b223-e5cbcb2a7483
card_faces[1].illustration_id:d8a037ea-c67b-4290-81ef-cdb8073c46cb
card_faces[1].image_uris.small:https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/small/back/3/6/3606519e-5677-4c21-a34e-be195b6669fa.jpg?1611000242
card_faces[1].image_uris.normal:https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/normal/back/3/6/3606519e-5677-4c21-a34e-be195b6669fa.jpg?1611000242
card_faces[1].image_uris.large:https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/large/back/3/6/3606519e-5677-4c21-a34e-be195b6669fa.jpg?1611000242
card_faces[1].image_uris.png:https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/png/back/3/6/3606519e-5677-4c21-a34e-be195b6669fa.png?1611000242
card_faces[1].image_uris.art_crop:https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/art_crop/back/3/6/3606519e-5677-4c21-a34e-be195b6669fa.jpg?1611000242
card_faces[1].image_uris.border_crop:https://c1.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-cards/border_crop/back/3/6/3606519e-5677-4c21-a34e-be195b6669fa.jpg?1611000242
legalities.standard:legal
legalities.future:legal
legalities.historic:legal
legalities.gladiator:legal
legalities.pioneer:legal
legalities.modern:legal
legalities.legacy:legal
legalities.pauper:not_legal
legalities.vintage:legal
legalities.penny:not_legal
legalities.commander:legal
legalities.brawl:legal
legalities.duel:legal
legalities.oldschool:not_legal
legalities.premodern:not_legal
games[0]:arena
games[1]:paper
games[2]:mtgo
reserved:False
foil:True
nonfoil:True
oversized:False
promo:False
reprint:False
variation:False
set:khm
set_name:Kaldheim
set_type:expansion
set_uri:https://api.scryfall.com/sets/43057fad-b1c1-437f-bc48-0045bce6d8c9
set_search_uri:https://api.scryfall.com/cards/search?order=set&q=e%3Akhm&unique=prints
scryfall_set_uri:https://scryfall.com/sets/khm?utm_source=api
rulings_uri:https://api.scryfall.com/cards/3606519e-5677-4c21-a34e-be195b6669fa/rulings
prints_search_uri:https://api.scryfall.com/cards/search?order=released&q=oracleid%3A35ae7b25-6d0f-49f8-a40d-dd2cf88e6f44&unique=prints
collector_number:21
digital:False
rarity:rare
card_back_id:0aeebaf5-8c7d-4636-9e82-8c27447861f7
artist:Jason Rainville
artist_ids[0]:6ed7e669-579b-443d-b223-e5cbcb2a7483
border_color:black
frame:2015
frame_effects[0]:legendary
full_art:False
textless:False
booster:True
story_spotlight:False
edhrec_rank:15706
preview.source:Marty Friedman
preview.source_uri:https://twitter.com/marty_friedman/status/1349527247560994816
preview.previewed_at:2021-01-13
prices.usd:0.87
prices.usd_foil:5.68
prices.eur:1.37
prices.eur_foil:2.00
prices.tix:
related_uris.gatherer:https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=503627
related_uris.tcgplayer_decks:https://decks.tcgplayer.com/magic/deck/search?contains=Reidane%2C+God+of+the+Worthy&page=1&utm_campaign=affiliate&utm_medium=api&utm_source=scryfall
related_uris.edhrec:https://edhrec.com/route/?cc=Reidane%2C+God+of+the+Worthy
related_uris.mtgtop8:https://mtgtop8.com/search?MD_check=1&SB_check=1&cards=Reidane%2C+God+of+the+Worthy
purchase_uris.tcgplayer:https://shop.tcgplayer.com/product/productsearch?id=230921&utm_campaign=affiliate&utm_medium=api&utm_source=scryfall
purchase_uris.cardmarket:https://www.cardmarket.com/en/Magic/Products/Singles/Kaldheim/Reidane-God-of-the-Worthy-Valkmira-Protectors-Shield?referrer=scryfall&utm_campaign=card_prices&utm_medium=text&utm_source=scryfall
purchase_uris.cardhoarder:https://www.cardhoarder.com/cards/87365?affiliate_id=scryfall&ref=card-profile&utm_campaign=affiliate&utm_medium=card&utm_source=scryfall
```

Comment: That is a way to do it, didn't tought in that. But I have a problem. Maybe missing something. When using your code I have several errors : "'JObject' is a class type and cannot be used as an expression." The same for JArray and JValue. Any clue what I'm missing?

Comment: Also have 'requestObject' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: Sorry, that's my bad; brain was in C# mode. Change `If o Is` to `If TypeOf o Is` and change `requestObject` to `o`

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I took your first example and pasted it into JsonUtils.com (not my favorite site but I didn't want the c#-vb conversion step I'd have had to do with QuickType)

It generates this:

```
Public Class ImageUris

    <JsonProperty("small")>
    Public Property Small As String

    <JsonProperty("normal")>
    Public Property Normal As String

    <JsonProperty("large")>
    Public Property Large As String

    <JsonProperty("png")>
    Public Property Png As String

    <JsonProperty("art_crop")>
    Public Property ArtCrop As String

    <JsonProperty("border_crop")>
    Public Property BorderCrop As String
End Class

Public Class CardFace

    <JsonProperty("object")>
    Public Property Object As String

    <JsonProperty("name")>
    Public Property Name As String

    <JsonProperty("mana_cost")>
    Public Property ManaCost As String

    <JsonProperty("type_line")>
    Public Property TypeLine As String

    <JsonProperty("oracle_text")>
    Public Property OracleText As String

    <JsonProperty("colors")>
    Public Property Colors As String()

    <JsonProperty("power")>
    Public Property Power As String

    <JsonProperty("toughness")>
    Public Property Toughness As String

    <JsonProperty("artist")>
    Public Property Artist As String

    <JsonProperty("artist_id")>
    Public Property ArtistId As String

    <JsonProperty("illustration_id")>
    Public Property IllustrationId As String

    <JsonProperty("image_uris")>
    Public Property ImageUris As ImageUris
End Class

Public Class Legalities

    <JsonProperty("standard")>
    Public Property Standard As String

    <JsonProperty("future")>
    Public Property Future As String

    <JsonProperty("historic")>
    Public Property Historic As String

    <JsonProperty("gladiator")>
    Public Property Gladiator As String

    <JsonProperty("pioneer")>
    Public Property Pioneer As String

    <JsonProperty("modern")>
    Public Property Modern As String

    <JsonProperty("legacy")>
    Public Property Legacy As String

    <JsonProperty("pauper")>
    Public Property Pauper As String

    <JsonProperty("vintage")>
    Public Property Vintage As String

    <JsonProperty("penny")>
    Public Property Penny As String

    <JsonProperty("commander")>
    Public Property Commander As String

    <JsonProperty("brawl")>
    Public Property Brawl As String

    <JsonProperty("duel")>
    Public Property Duel As String

    <JsonProperty("oldschool")>
    Public Property Oldschool As String

    <JsonProperty("premodern")>
    Public Property Premodern As String
End Class

Public Class Preview

    <JsonProperty("source")>
    Public Property Source As String

    <JsonProperty("source_uri")>
    Public Property SourceUri As String

    <JsonProperty("previewed_at")>
    Public Property PreviewedAt As String
End Class

Public Class Prices

    <JsonProperty("usd")>
    Public Property Usd As String

    <JsonProperty("usd_foil")>
    Public Property UsdFoil As String

    <JsonProperty("eur")>
    Public Property Eur As String

    <JsonProperty("eur_foil")>
    Public Property EurFoil As String

    <JsonProperty("tix")>
    Public Property Tix As Object
End Class

Public Class RelatedUris

    <JsonProperty("gatherer")>
    Public Property Gatherer As String

    <JsonProperty("tcgplayer_decks")>
    Public Property TcgplayerDecks As String

    <JsonProperty("edhrec")>
    Public Property Edhrec As String

    <JsonProperty("mtgtop8")>
    Public Property Mtgtop8 As String
End Class

Public Class PurchaseUris

    <JsonProperty("tcgplayer")>
    Public Property Tcgplayer As String

    <JsonProperty("cardmarket")>
    Public Property Cardmarket As String

    <JsonProperty("cardhoarder")>
    Public Property Cardhoarder As String
End Class

Public Class Root

    <JsonProperty("object")>
    Public Property Object As String

    <JsonProperty("id")>
    Public Property Id As String

    <JsonProperty("oracle_id")>
    Public Property OracleId As String

    <JsonProperty("multiverse_ids")>
    Public Property MultiverseIds As Integer()

    <JsonProperty("mtgo_id")>
    Public Property MtgoId As Integer

    <JsonProperty("arena_id")>
    Public Property ArenaId As Integer

    <JsonProperty("tcgplayer_id")>
    Public Property TcgplayerId As Integer

    <JsonProperty("cardmarket_id")>
    Public Property CardmarketId As Integer

    <JsonProperty("name")>
    Public Property Name As String

    <JsonProperty("lang")>
    Public Property Lang As String

    <JsonProperty("released_at")>
    Public Property ReleasedAt As String

    <JsonProperty("uri")>
    Public Property Uri As String

    <JsonProperty("scryfall_uri")>
    Public Property ScryfallUri As String

    <JsonProperty("layout")>
    Public Property Layout As String

    <JsonProperty("highres_image")>
    Public Property HighresImage As Boolean

    <JsonProperty("cmc")>
    Public Property Cmc As Double

    <JsonProperty("type_line")>
    Public Property TypeLine As String

    <JsonProperty("color_identity")>
    Public Property ColorIdentity As String()

    <JsonProperty("keywords")>
    Public Property Keywords As String()

    <JsonProperty("card_faces")>
    Public Property CardFaces As CardFace()

    <JsonProperty("legalities")>
    Public Property Legalities As Legalities

    <JsonProperty("games")>
    Public Property Games As String()

    <JsonProperty("reserved")>
    Public Property Reserved As Boolean

    <JsonProperty("foil")>
    Public Property Foil As Boolean

    <JsonProperty("nonfoil")>
    Public Property Nonfoil As Boolean

    <JsonProperty("oversized")>
    Public Property Oversized As Boolean

    <JsonProperty("promo")>
    Public Property Promo As Boolean

    <JsonProperty("reprint")>
    Public Property Reprint As Boolean

    <JsonProperty("variation")>
    Public Property Variation As Boolean

    <JsonProperty("set")>
    Public Property Set As String

    <JsonProperty("set_name")>
    Public Property SetName As String

    <JsonProperty("set_type")>
    Public Property SetType As String

    <JsonProperty("set_uri")>
    Public Property SetUri As String

    <JsonProperty("set_search_uri")>
    Public Property SetSearchUri As String

    <JsonProperty("scryfall_set_uri")>
    Public Property ScryfallSetUri As String

    <JsonProperty("rulings_uri")>
    Public Property RulingsUri As String

    <JsonProperty("prints_search_uri")>
    Public Property PrintsSearchUri As String

    <JsonProperty("collector_number")>
    Public Property CollectorNumber As String

    <JsonProperty("digital")>
    Public Property Digital As Boolean

    <JsonProperty("rarity")>
    Public Property Rarity As String

    <JsonProperty("card_back_id")>
    Public Property CardBackId As String

    <JsonProperty("artist")>
    Public Property Artist As String

    <JsonProperty("artist_ids")>
    Public Property ArtistIds As String()

    <JsonProperty("border_color")>
    Public Property BorderColor As String

    <JsonProperty("frame")>
    Public Property Frame As String

    <JsonProperty("frame_effects")>
    Public Property FrameEffects As String()

    <JsonProperty("full_art")>
    Public Property FullArt As Boolean

    <JsonProperty("textless")>
    Public Property Textless As Boolean

    <JsonProperty("booster")>
    Public Property Booster As Boolean

    <JsonProperty("story_spotlight")>
    Public Property StorySpotlight As Boolean

    <JsonProperty("edhrec_rank")>
    Public Property EdhrecRank As Integer

    <JsonProperty("preview")>
    Public Property Preview As Preview

    <JsonProperty("prices")>
    Public Property Prices As Prices

    <JsonProperty("related_uris")>
    Public Property RelatedUris As RelatedUris

    <JsonProperty("purchase_uris")>
    Public Property PurchaseUris As PurchaseUris
End Class
```

Then I add a Nuget package of Newtonsoft.Json...

And I can then write:

```
Dim j = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Root)(JSON_Response)
```

Now I can just walk around the `j` and pull things out of it:

```
j.OracleId

For Each k as String in j.Keywords
  ...

For Each cf as CardFace in j.CardFaces
  For Each c as String in cf.Colors
    ...
```

You only need to support the minimum number of properties in your classes to make your code go. The json can contain more or fewer; more will be ignored, fewer will be `Nothing`..

Comment: Understood. But my main goal it's to get all the information, in a row. If the generated jSON have more fields than I found, I will miss them. Also, this seems I need to specify a loop for the subkeys I want. Which I would like is something like: I got the jSON file. A loop goes to all the keys and subkeys in order and retrieve all information. In this case, if there is a key I don't have in my class, it will be ignored.

Comment: *All the information in a row* -> replace all the newlines in the json with nothing

Comment: Maybe I didn't explained well. I would like to iterate all json. Not needing to use "j.keywords" or "j.cardfaces". Basically for each key that exists (nested or not, duplicated or not), would get the value, starting in the first key until the last one, without missing any key.

Comment: Your solution, despite could work, make me create multiple for each loops and would not let me create it automatically without putting the "key" names.